# How can SQL syntax errors be found?

Tags: sql

Generally SQL errors are less descriptive than other languages, and on big chunks of sql code it may be really hard to find the error when your only information is "syntax error near >insert place where the error isn't near here<".

I'm willing to know if there is some software or methods that helps on finding this kind of problem more easily.

Comment: Each DBMS has its own way to tell you where the error is and, once you get used to the particulars of the DBMS messages, it is rather straightforward to find out what the issue is. It is simply a matter of **getting to know** the platform you are using.

Comment: MySQL, for instance, tells me I have a syntax error in a 30 lines block, and I can't even be sure the error is in this block because it already said it was in the wrong block before. The error messages are absolutely unreliable and ambiguous.

Comment: Why don't you add to your question the code in question as well as the error message? That would help us help you.

Comment: I visited many questions in which people had my error and there was no one which was like another or like the mine. This made me write this question, because I find that MySQL errors are ambiguous and posting the code block wouldn't help no one else, just like the others didn't help.

Comment: Well, for MySQL syntax errors, usually the best first point (whilst learning the language) is to *check the manual* for each statement/function/clause you're trying to write and make sure that your code matches what the manual says you can do. But the advice to *check the manual*, despite being included in these error messages, is frequently ignored.

Comment: I have over a hundred of the same clause written -- apparently -- correctly. The problem isn't conceptual but with traditional mistakes that occur when programming. The error message should indicate what is the error correctly. You can't blame me for the error message being imprecise.

Comment: No, there's no way for SQL to be more precise because your entire query is one big command. The best you can do is break up your SQL query into simple steps and keep introducing parts back until it breaks. Hopefully the last thing you added was what was wrong. Sorry, but that's what I always end up doing when I think my statement is right, but SQL says "there's an error somehere near SELECT" or something.

Comment: I agree that mysql could be *more* helpful but it (and MariaDB fork) are somewhat alone in how bad they are. For instance, if MySQL reports "incorrect syntax near `FOO`", then you need to look at each `FOO` and work out *what context it's appearing in*. Are you inside a `CASE` expression and it's expecting a `WHEN` or `ELSE`, for example? Other database systems are more explicit "found `FOO`, was expecting `<when clause>` or `<else clause>`" would be more helpful. And most will give line/character numbers so you don't have to "hunt the `FOO`".

Comment: BTW: in practice, most of the errors are actually semantic errors.Syntax errors are relatively easy to catch ("found xxx when expecting ',' or ')' in line yyy::  "SELECT  abc xxx omg FROM zzz") , unless the parser tries to resync and consumed too many tokens in the process.

Comment: DBA with several years experience here. Never had problems with this. The error message always tells exactly where the error is. It's not somewhere near and after the mentioned place. It's to the **left** of where MySQL says it is. MySQL simply reports the first thing that doesn't make sense. The only error messages, that aren't 100% clear, are when `the error is near ''`. But then you still have a line number, and it's either a missing `;` in the line before, or a delimiter isn't set correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You can carefully examine the query for things that

- Should *not* be there, but are, like "the wrong kind of quote" or an extra quote inside a string
- Should be there but are not, like an end quote

If that doesn't work, you can start commenting out sections of the query until it works. For example comment out the entire WHERE clause. If it works you know there's something wrong in the WHERE clause. If not, you know it's somewhere else.

Keep simplifying the query until it's runable, then you'll have an idea where to look for the problem.

To quote Futurama, the error messages are "technically correct, which is the best kind of correct" Yes, there's a syntax error somewhere, but no, it's not usually going to tell you where.

Just keep dividing it up until you find the broken part.

Comment: Another related technique is to actually *introduce* an error, by inserting a token somewhere in the sql body, and play binary search on that